# Integrate a finished web service in a Android application

Tags: java, android, web-services, rest

I don't know if the correct term is "integrate" or "connect" a finished web service in a android application. I mean,

1. Is there any possibility to "integrate" a finished RESTful Web Service in a Android application, which I have not developed, yet.?

Otherwise,

2. Are there some steps to develop a RESTful web service which I need to use from a Android application?

The last question is asked because I don't know if the first step is to finish my RESTful Web Service and then integrate it in my android application or or developing the RESTful web service and the android application at the same time.

In any case, **how I can do it well**? I need help to organise my mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need three things:

1. Client(your app)
2. Server
3. Database

Lets say you have to create a login service for your app. Then your steps should be like given below:

1. Create a login form with android UI.
2. Get username and password from Edit Texts in strings.
3. Send these credentials to server(via http reqest).
4. At client side read response from url via input stream.
5. At the server side, use a server side technology in which you are familiar with.(If you are not familiar with any server side tech. I strongly recommend you php.)
6. Select/update/compare (Whatever you want) in data base and return response as a json string.

You can use server on your system. I suggest to use XAMPP(cross platform apache mysql php perl). As its name says, it includes server+database+php (its local). It will create a local apache server on your machine.

Follow this : [XAMPP Tutorial](https://blog.udemy.com/xampp-tutorial/) , [Working with XAMPP](http://www.phpknowhow.com/basics/working-with-xampp/)

Here are some nice tutorials of web services with android:

[How to connect Android with PHP, MySQL](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)

[Using Database from an Android Application](http://javapapers.com/android/using-database-from-an-android-application/)

Comment: Ok, I would try to finish a small example with the RESTful Web Service and when I will test it I will start my project under your recommendations. Thanks you!